# Hide a button if non of Checkbox is checked on a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have a table with checkbox at the beginning of a row. I have a button that is hidden. If I check one checkbox the button shows. If I uncheck it, the button hides. It works fine. My problem is, if I have all checkboxes "checked" and uncheck one checkbox from those checked ones, the button hides. It should not hide because there are still checkboxes checked. How am I going to fix this?

Here is my code

Script:

```
$('table').on('change', ':checkbox', function(){
    if (!this.checked) 
    {
        $('#delete').hide();
    }

    else
    {
        $('#delete').show();
    }


});
```

Html:

```
<table class="table table-hover table-condensed" style = "font-size: 13px;">
                <tr>
                    <th><input type ="checkbox" id = "chkall"></th>
                    <th>Type</th>
                    <th>Brand</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <th>Serial No</th>
                    <th>Asset No</th>
                    <th>Date of Purchased</th>
                    <th>Warranty Expiration</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td><input type ="checkbox"></td>
                    <td>Keyboard</td>
                    <td>HP</td>
                    <td>One time use keyboard</td>
                    <td>123456</td>
                    <td>789456</td>
                    <td>July 5, 2019</td>
                    <td>August 6, 2015</td>
                    <td>Available</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td><input type ="checkbox"></td>
                    <td>Keyboard</td>
                    <td>HP</td>
                    <td>One time use keyboard</td>
                    <td>123456</td>
                    <td>789456</td>
                    <td>July 5, 2019</td>
                    <td>August 6, 2015</td>
                    <td>Available</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td><input type ="checkbox"></td>
                    <td>Keyboard</td>
                    <td>HP</td>
                    <td>One time use keyboard</td>
                    <td>123456</td>
                    <td>789456</td>
                    <td>July 5, 2019</td>
                    <td>August 6, 2015</td>
                    <td>Available</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td><input type ="checkbox"></td>
                    <td>Keyboard</td>
                    <td>HP</td>
                    <td>One time use keyboard</td>
                    <td>123456</td>
                    <td>789456</td>
                    <td>July 5, 2019</td>
                    <td>August 6, 2015</td>
                    <td>Available</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td><input type ="checkbox"></td>
                    <td>Keyboard</td>
                    <td>HP</td>
                    <td>One time use keyboard</td>
                    <td>123456</td>
                    <td>789456</td>
                    <td>July 5, 2019</td>
                    <td>August 6, 2015</td>
                    <td>Available</td>
                </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check whether at least one checkbox is checked like

```js
$('table').on('change', ':checkbox', function() {
  $('#delete').toggle(!!$('input:checkbox:checked').length);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="display: none" id="delete">delete</div>
<table class="table table-hover table-condensed" style="font-size: 13px;">
  <tr>
    <th>
      <input type="checkbox" id="chkall">
    </th>
    <th>Type</th>
    <th>Brand</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Serial No</th>
    <th>Asset No</th>
    <th>Date of Purchased</th>
    <th>Warranty Expiration</th>
    <th>Status</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox">
    </td>
    <td>Keyboard</td>
    <td>HP</td>
    <td>One time use keyboard</td>
    <td>123456</td>
    <td>789456</td>
    <td>July 5, 2019</td>
    <td>August 6, 2015</td>
    <td>Available</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox">
    </td>
    <td>Keyboard</td>
    <td>HP</td>
    <td>One time use keyboard</td>
    <td>123456</td>
    <td>789456</td>
    <td>July 5, 2019</td>
    <td>August 6, 2015</td>
    <td>Available</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox">
    </td>
    <td>Keyboard</td>
    <td>HP</td>
    <td>One time use keyboard</td>
    <td>123456</td>
    <td>789456</td>
    <td>July 5, 2019</td>
    <td>August 6, 2015</td>
    <td>Available</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox">
    </td>
    <td>Keyboard</td>
    <td>HP</td>
    <td>One time use keyboard</td>
    <td>123456</td>
    <td>789456</td>
    <td>July 5, 2019</td>
    <td>August 6, 2015</td>
    <td>Available</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox">
    </td>
    <td>Keyboard</td>
    <td>HP</td>
    <td>One time use keyboard</td>
    <td>123456</td>
    <td>789456</td>
    <td>July 5, 2019</td>
    <td>August 6, 2015</td>
    <td>Available</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```